# Mysql query for counting winnings and losings

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some columns. One of the column registers if the row is true or false. E.g if you lost the game, this is set to 0 else 1.

What I want to count is the amount of 1 in row. The table looks like this:

```
+-----------+
|game_status|
|-----------|
|00000000   |
|-----------|
|00000000   |
|-----------|
|00000001   |
|-----------|
|00000001   |
|-----------|
|00000001   |
|-----------|
| ...       |
+-----------+
```

So if you count it by hand the result would be:
starting from 0:

```
lost(0) ->  0 - 1 =
lost(0) -> -1 - 1 = 
 won(1) -> -2 + 1 =
 won(1) -> -1 + 1 =
 won(1) ->  0 + 1 =
```

Result = 1

So how do I get this result using mysql queries? I have tried using count but it counts all ones or zeros.

Thanks in advance.

I think I got a little bit confused when I accepted the answer and I do apologize for that. What I think I forgot to say is the result of the query should look like this:

```
+--------+------+
|   1    | -1   |
|--------|------|
|   2    | -2   |
|--------|------|
|   3    | -1   |
+---------------+
```

There the incremental column is the amount of games played...

Comment: Have you tried using the sum function()?  Or using a where clause with your count() function to separate the games that were won or lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could count the wins and subtract the count of the loses.

```
select (select count(status) from table1 where status = 1) - 
       (select count(status) from table1 where status = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Column = 0 THEN 1 END) AS TotalZeros, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Column = 1 THEN 1 END) AS TotalOnes
FROM YourTable
```

Or much simpler way is if your column only holds either **0** or **1** just select count of either one of them and subtract it from the total rows which will give you the count of other.

Comment: yeah, this gives me an error though: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 END) AS TotalZeros, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN game_status = 1 1 END) AS' at line 1 I tried to add the zeros too, the type bit puts them there by default, but I still get the error. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @Mnemonics thats because you copied the code wrong. You need THEN after 1

Answer (score 0):

Use SUM instead of COUNT. COUNT finds the number of items regardless of their value, SUM actually totals up the integer values.
Look here for reference
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(CASE game_status WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE -1 end) FROM table_name;
```